# Parallelizing a series of independent sequential lines of code

Tags: openmp, sequential

What is the best way to execute multiple lines of code in parallel if they are not dependent of each other? (I'm using OpenMP)

Pseudo code:

```
database->connect()
openfile("stuff.txt")
ping("stackoverflow.com")
x = 2;
y = a + b;
```

The only way I can come up with is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
switch (i) {
case 0: database->connect(); break;
...
```

I haven't tried it, but I also remember that you're not supposed to `break` while using OpenMP

Comment: Were each of these individual lines so slow that they need to be parallelized? Think about this from a `pthread` perspective; would you want to launch each line as a function on its own separate thread? There's enormous overhead to doing this.

Comment: I agree with chrisaycock. The overhead is going to be extremely high for the little amount of work you are doing. If you really want to try it, take a look at the OpenMP sections directive.

Comment: Much more of a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm assuming that the indivdual things you listed as independant tasks were just examples.  If they really are things like `y=a+b`, then as @chrisaycock and @ejd have said, they're too small for this sort of parallelism (eg thread based, as opposed to ILP or something) to actually take advantage of the concurrency due to overheads.  But if they are bigger operations, the way to do task-based parallelism in OpenMP is with the `task` directive: eg,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void work(int *v) {
    *v = omp_get_thread_num();
    sleep(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a, b, c;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp task shared(a) default(none)
            work(&a);

            #pragma omp task shared(b) default(none)
            work(&b);

            #pragma omp task shared(c) default(none)
            work(&c);
        }
    }
    printf("a,b,c = %d,%d,%d\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggested sections because I was not sure what compiler you are using.  If your compiler supports OpenMP V3.0, then you can also try tasks - though they have more overhead in most implementations than sections.